# Roll two fair dice, what is the expected value of rolls such that the sum of the two faces is the multiple of 6.

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, dice

I was thinking that there were 2 cases:

(1) $\\$  $X_{1}+X_{2}=6$, and the probability would be $\dfrac{5}{36}$.

(2) $\\$  $X_{1}=X_{2}=6$, and the probability would be $\dfrac{1}{36}$.

I am now stuck here, any hints or ideas would be great.

Comment: Are the two outcomes mutually exclusive? If so you can add the probabilities.

Comment: Call getting a sum which is a multiple of $6$ a success. Then by your work the probability of success on one roll of the two dice is $1/6$. The number $X$ of trials until the first success has geometric distribution, parameter $p=1/6$. The mean of $X$ is $1/p$.

Comment: Cool! I figure it out. Thank you to both of you!